# Inequality :$\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^{\tan^2(x)}+\left(\frac{1}{1+3}\right)^{\tan^2(1)}+\left(\frac{3}{x+3}\right)^{\tan^2(3)}>\frac{40}{39}$

Tags: inequality, exponentiation, constants, convexity-inequality

Claim :

Let $\frac{13}{10}\leq x<\frac{\pi}{2}$

$$f(x)=\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^{\tan^2(x)}+\left(\frac{1}{1+3}\right)^{\tan^2(1)}+\left(\frac{3}{x+3}\right)^{\tan^2(3)}>\frac{40}{39}$$

The function in the RHS is close to a  line and the choice of $\frac{40}{39}$ is because it's a simple constant and rational .As you can see I'm inspired by the Nesbitt's inequality so it's not totally random .

To prove I have tried convexity with the second derivative of $f(x)$ wich is positive but I cannot prove it currently .

Any idea to prove it ?

Thanks !

Comment: The command of Mathematica `NMinimize[{(x/(x + 1))^(Tan[x]^2) + (1/
      4)^(Tan[1]^2) + (3/(x + 3))^(Tan[3]^2), x >= 13/10 && x <= 9/5},
  x]` produces $\{1.02528,\{x\to 1.77772\}\}$, whereas $\frac {40} {39}=1.02564\dots.$

Comment: @user64494 one of the interval was false my fault !

Comment: `NMinimize[{(x/(x + 1))^(Tan[x]^2) + (1/
      4)^(Tan[1]^2) + (3/(x + 3))^(Tan[3]^2), 
  x >= 13/10 && x <= Pi/2}, x]` produces $\{1.02613,\{x\to 1.5708\}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

*Fact 1*: If $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$, then $g(x) = \tan^2 x \ln (\frac{x}{x+1})$ is strictly decreasing.
(Hint: Take derivative and use $\tan x \ge x$.)

Now, by Fact 1, we have $f(x) \ge f(\pi/2) > \frac{40}{39}$. We are done.